# Async passthrough methods

Tags: c#, async-await

When bubbling up asynchrony, given a method whose only purpose is to call another asynchronous method with a specific parameter, which of the follow is the accepted/preferred pattern, and why?

```
async Task MyMethodAsync() => await MyOtherMethodAsync(1);
```

or

```
Task MyMethodAsync() => MyOtherMethodAsync(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer:

```
Task MyMethodAsync() => MyOtherMethodAsync(1);
```

Using `async` and `await` actually adds quite a bit of overhead to build a full state machine, where the 2nd is just a simple method call.

The only potential advantage to making the method `async` itself would be if you wanted to add exception handling, and have the stack trace be the local method, or log the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the latter, it doesn't set up an extra `async` state machine only to do nothing with it.